# URL-Encoded post parameters don't Bind to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have the following Model

```
namespace ClientAPI.Models {

    public class Internal {

        public class ReportRequest {

            public DateTime StartTime;
            public DateTime EndTime;
            public string FileName;
            public string UserName;
            public string Password;
        }
    }
}
```

with the following method:

```
[HttpPost]
 public HttpResponseMessage GetQuickbooksOFXService(Internal.ReportRequest Request){       
     return GetQuickbooksOFXService(Request.UserName, 
         Request.Password, Request.StartTime, Request.EndTime, Request.FileName);
 }
```

My webform looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:56772/Internal/GetQuickbooksOFXService"    target="_blank">
<input type="text" name="StartTime" value="2013-04-03T00:00:00">
<input type="text" name="EndTime" value="2013-05-04T00:00:00">
<input type="text" name="FileName" value="Export_2013-04-03_to_2013-05-03.qbo">
<input type="text" name="UserName" value="UserName">
<input type="text" name="Password" value="*****">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
```

My question is:

I get into the GetQuickbooksOFXService function but my model has all nulls in it instead something useful.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more testing I found that not only does the properties in the class need to be public but you also need a get and set method.  so after making the following it started working.

```
  public class ReportRequest
    {
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```